# NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Tags: python, database, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I want to make thing like when member join and bot join a guild, I get information about members in guilds like: id, guild id. warns and reason.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self,member):
        values = {
            "_id":member.id,
            "guild_id": guild.id,
            "warns": 0 ,
            "reasons": []
        }
        if collusers.count_documents({"_id": member.id, "guild_id": self.bot.guild.id}) == 0:
            collusers.insert_one(values) 

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(guild):
        server_values = {
            "_id": guild.id,
            "case": 0,
        }
        if collservers.count_documents ({"_id": guild.id}) == 0:
            collservers.insert_one(server_values)
```

I have error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andriyko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 351, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Andriyko\Desktop\Ghostbot\modules\warn.py", line 39, in on_member_join
    "guild_id": guild.id,
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

Comment: Evidently `guild` is not defined at that place in the code.

Comment: Replac guild.id with self.bot.guild.id in " on member join"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `guild` defined in the first listener `on_member_join`. You can easily get the guild though with the member argument that is passed through.

Another thing I noticed was that you're passing in `self.bot.guild.id` which won't work since the bot can be in multiple guilds (and there isn't a `guild` property of `self.bot`. Just use `member.guild.id` again here.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self,member):
    guild = member.guild
    values = {
        "_id":member.id,
        "guild_id": guild.id,
        "warns": 0 ,
        "reasons": []
    }
    if collusers.count_documents({"_id": member.id, "guild_id": guild.id}) == 0:
        collusers.insert_one(values)
```

Comment: All good, but what about on guild join?

Comment: @Maron I don't believe that there is an error for `on_guild_join` that you have. That listener wasn't related to the error you had too